# onedit() is not working when data is pasted or queried for timestamping,

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Hi I am using this script to timestamp my entries in google sheet but its only giving me date when data is entered manually , its not working when data is pasted in multiple cell or is when query is used . how can i make it work when data is pasted or queried .

```
 function onEdit() {
       var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
       if( s.getName() == "data02" ) { 
       var r = s.getActiveCell();
 if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { 
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
    if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
    nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
```

}
}

Comment: In order to support pasting you will have to use the event object to determine the range.

Comment: @MetaMan apparently not recently enough!

Comment: You do have access to the range  via `e.range and e.range.columnStart, e.range.columnEnd,er.range.rowStart and e.range.rowEnd` not all of it is published in the documentation but it's been there for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "data02" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.columnEnd == 1) {
    //e.source.toast('cond');
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: HI the copying part is working but in a new sheet and i am using this query =QUERY(data02!A:A ,"SELECT * ") to  export that data the in column 1 and timestamp should be in column 2 but its  not working at all . 
please go through this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V5fWsRJfKmlb8KJqIoe6wweBTrpCwXxwApBkWG50FFQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's because the query is not a user edit and it does not generate an onedit trigger

Comment: how can i make it work with query or any other method you know of which can be useful here?

Comment: I suppose you could do the query with a script and have the script do it.   You could even have the script call the onedit if you provide the event object correctly.